# Counting numbers in an random array

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to find how many of each number from zero to ten is generated in a random array. 
I created a random array list

```
    i=0;
    var ranList=[];
    while (i<20){
      i++;
      ranList.push(Math.floor(10*Math.random()));
    }
    //count each number
    document.write(ranList.sort().join("<br>"));

/*Then I made a function to count /elements from this array 
*/


    function ctnumber(array,elem){
      var ct=0;
      var j =0;
        while(j<array.length)
        {
        j++;
          if(array[j]==elem){
          ct+=1;}
         }
      }
      return ct;
      }
      alert(ctnumber(ranList,5));
```

The second function doesn't execute,  any idea why?

Thank you!

Comment: Might help if you clean up your code a bit and also show your code as it appears, rather than as two snippets.

Comment: "Doesn't execute"?! Like, *at all*?! We can't tell you why that is based on what you show.

Comment: Do you know of the Javascript console? It gives you information about syntax errors and runtime errors.

Comment: because of extra closing bracket.

Comment: You have an extra `}` after the `ct+=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should avoid using the name array for you variable:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Your brackets are also wrong. Change your function to this and it should work:

```
function ctnumber(arr,elem){
      var ct=0;
      var j =0;
        while(j<arr.length)
        {
        j++;
          if(arr[j]==elem){
          ct+=1;}
         }
      return ct;
      }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and would be better served as a comment.

Comment: Thank you,  that solves it.  For some reason array didn't give trouble as a variable,  maybe because it was on lowercaps ...

Comment: @user5723270 there should be no reason for `array` as a variable name causing an issue, unless you are using 3rd party library's that do something to it. `Array` with a capital `A` is the name of the "object" that array's derive from. However, as stated in this answer, it's generally not a good idea to give any variable a name that is the same as an inbuilt type or function (IE: Number, Object, Array, String, Math, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, as stated by Pardeep in his comment, is that you have an extra `}` after your `ct+=1;` in your second `while` loop.

The correct code would be: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/raqmcaqe/)

```
i = 0;
var ranList = [];
while (i < 20) {
  i++;
  ranList.push(Math.floor(10 * Math.random()));
}
//count each number
document.write(ranList.sort().join("<br>"));

function ctnumber(array, elem) {
  var ct = 0;
  var j = 0;
  while (j < array.length) {
    j++;
    if (array[j] == elem) {
      ct += 1; // NOTE NO } HERE NOW
    }
  }
  return ct;
}
alert(ctnumber(ranList, 5));
```

I also suggest a bit of a code cleanup:

```
var i = 0;
var ranList = [];
while (i < 20) {
    i++;
    ranList.push(Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
}

function countNumbers(list, elem) {
    var count = 0;
    // For loops are generally more readable for looping through existing lists
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == elem) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
alert(countNumber(ranList, 5));
```

Please note that `console.log()` is a much better debugging tool, it can be accessed by `F12` in Firefox and Chrome/IE.

Comment: Thank you I'm using the android app aide Web to code,  I'll find out how to use the console in it